# How To Open Visual Studio Code Using Terminal

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-code

Recently I downloaded visual studio code which operates as text editor but I can't figure out how to open code file from terminal.

When I use Sublime Text the command is `subl`, so when I run `subl newFolder.c` it would automatically open Sublime Text with a file named `newFolder.c`.

What can I type to create/open a file in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Related: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Comment: Did you try; gedit newFolder.c; nano newFolder.c; vim newFolder.c ??

Comment: @Rahul none of them work

Comment: If none of those worked, your `PATH` is likely wacked.  What does `echo $PATH` show you?  What you expected?

Comment: Instead of `ctrl +shift+P` ... `install shell ...` try going to the same place `ctrl+shift+P` and typing in `install 'Code' command in PATH`. This worked for me when none of the other solutions did. I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30627956

Comment: @Ricky: This is exactly what [Shane's answer](/a/906641/175814) suggests.

Answer (score 106):

It should be called `code` and for me, I just have to run it.

```
$ code
$ code my-file
```

and that works.  If installed the .deb (only available in older Ubuntu versions) the path should be

```
`/usr/bin/code`
```

If you installed it as a snap, e.g.

```
$ sudo snap install code --classic
```

Then it's path should be

```
`/snap/bin/code`
```

If you installed it another way, then try to find the binary, e.g.

```
command -v code
```

will print the path. `command` is a bit more reliable than `which`.    VS Code is an Electron application (i.e. Chrome/node) and the launcher is a little wonky.   For example, `xdg-open` does not work well for me.

NOTE ABOUT INSIDERS VERSION:
As Nicholas Humphrey points out in the comments, it could also be called `code-insiders` if you installed the insiders version.  This allows you to have side-by-side installations of regular and insider versions.

Comment: yeah!! worked for me.

Comment: "code ." 
will open current directory in vs code

Comment: Important notice: Only worked for me when I installed the debian package. It did NOT work when I installed the snap package - then I could open VS Code via GUI, but I don't know which command to use.

Comment: @MartinThoma I added some more info for `snap` installs.  Also, see @DavidFoerster answer below.  It should fix up the shell command if it's broken.

Comment: OMG! Been weeks looking for information and trying every single keyword and it is as easy as just  `code`? Thank you!

Comment: none of these works for me, this is weird...really wish Linux could be as easy as Windows. In Windows it's just `code.` at any directory but in Linux it doesn't work.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey, sorry it's not going well for you.  If you post your specific problem we might be able to help.

Comment: @MichaelSandman thanks, I figured it out a while ago actually. My version is the insider version so I need to call code insider instead of just code. Stupid me~~

Comment: For those people (like me) who installed VS Code through the GUI on Ubuntu, but don't know how to setup the command line option these two commands should work for you  (Note the source below says use path `/usr/bin` instead, but mine was in `/snap/bin`): `sudo update-alternatives --set editor /snap/bin/code` and if that throws an error run this first then the other `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor $(which code) 10` Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Answer (score 42):

Correct way is to open Visual Studio Code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Windows (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac) then type `Install 'code' command in PATH` . At some point you should see an option come up that lets you install shell command, click it. Then open a new terminal window and type `code`.

Comment: That option isn't coming up in 1.25.1

Comment: @silencedmessage try typing `shell`. [This is what it looks like for me](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kS1CtsQDQF8BNeR8v7ReBaQHWNJXvzKw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: For mac OS you should use CMD+Shift+P

Comment: Instead of `install shell command`, for me it was `Install 'code' command in PATH`

Comment: It seems i cannot find either `install shell command` or `Install 'code' command in PATH` in 1.53.2 :/ . Anyone experiencing a similar issue ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. Did somebody find a solution? I would like to open Visual Code from the command line.