# How to create `vscode` or `code` command line by launch visual studio code from terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, visual-studio-code

In Ubuntu 20.04, after download from various ways (**snap** or **ubuntu software**) the **visual studio code** text editor, I had not been able to  find a way to install the shortcut command line `vscode` or `code`.

I used alias by open the current path:

```bsh
alias c.='(code $PWD &>/dev/null &)'
```

But since this won't work without the line command `code`.

I tried the [suggestions found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852076/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-using-terminal?answertab=active#tab-top), to open **Visual Studio Code** and press `Ctrl+Shift+P` then type `>install shell command` but I got **command not found**.

Comment: If you have a solution to your problem, post an answer please, instead of putting it in the question. That said, the default Ubuntu configuration will add snap commands to the PATH, so if it doesn't, then you must have messed up something.

Comment: Making symlink to /usr/bin/code is bad practice. The better is to make link to /usr/local/bin/code

Comment: I did it @muru, thanks for you suggestions. I may have damaged something in **snap**, but I only had this problem with **visual studio code** with snap. Finally I left the installation I did with **ubuntu software**

Answer (score 0):

**Solution reached:**

- Find `vscode_path` where is **visual studio code** installed.
  Suppose that is `/snap/code/current/usr/share/code/bin/code`
- Create a symlink from `<vscode_path>` **bin** command to `/usr/bin`

```bsh
rm -f /usr/bin/code
ln -s /snap/code/current/usr/share/code/bin/code /usr/local/bin/code
```

The latter would create a `code` line command to launch from the terminal

Comment: I have followed @N0rbert recommendation to use `/usr/local/bin/code` instead of `/usr/bin/code`.

Comment: @Norbert Wouldn't it be better if ```/snap/code/current/usr/share/code/bin``` be added to the PATH variable?